# magnetic flux winding

Tags: electromagnetism

If an electric wire carrying some current is wound on a soft iron core, the magnetic flux increases according to the winding turns.

Does the same hold for winding the core, eg. winding a soft iron wire around a straight electric wire? Does the field strength at the iron wire's ends also increase according to the turns? And if, why do we never see such iron "coils" in electric machines?

Comment: No, no…………………,.,

Comment: If you join the ends of your soft iron wire then you have made a current transformer with a very long magnetic path.

Comment: It doesn't, and I don't have the time to write up a proper answer, but the fact that you're asking this question shows that you're putting together things you've learned and really *thinking* about them, which is commendable!